# Method that reloads view when the day changes

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I am trying to create a method that runs in the background in my `SummaryViewController` that waits for the day to change, and then reloads it's own view.

(By the way, the date I'm waiting to see change is yesterday...so basically when yesterday becomes today, I want the view to reload.  So `self.dateLabel.text!` is equal to yesterdays date.)

This is the `viewDidAppear()` in my `SummaryViewController`

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // Background task that checks for when the day changes
    while true {
        sleep(1)
        self.yesterday = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: -2, toDate: NSDate(), options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))
        var yesterdayDateString = self.formatDate(self.yesterday!)
        if (self.dateLabel.text! != yesterdayDateString) {
            print("balls")
            self.view.setNeedsDisplay()

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use NSTimer and not a while loop.

```
 NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: "check", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

and then in your **check** function, compare current date with a global variable holding the start date and see if the day has changed.